# Jackson how to parse a filed which is also date value

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have `HashMap<LocalDate,SundayServerValue>` from which save data as json to file

```
HashMap<LocalDate,SundayServerValue>
```

I make json string like this

```
String jsonToSaved = ob.writeValueAsString(sundayUpdateDateMap);
```

or this

```
ob.writeValue(new File(pathToSundayMapFile), sundayUpdateDateMap);
```

This is how String jsonToSaved looks like

Both return the same json format where there is no `"data":"yyyy-MM-dd"` just `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

```
{"2018-08-05":[{"ip":"1.7.2.3","window1":true,"window2":false}, 
{"ip":"2.1.2.2","window1":false,"window2":true}]}
```

Classes

```
import json.LocalDateDeSerializer;

public class SundayJsonTemplate {

@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeSerializer.class)
private LocalDate date;
private ArrayList<SundayServerValue> sundayServerValueList;

public SundayJsonTemplate() {
}

public SundayJsonTemplate(LocalDate date, ArrayList<SundayServerValue> 
sundayServerValueList) {
    this.date = date;
    this.setSundayServerValueList(sundayServerValueList);
}
[...]

}



public class SundayServerValue {
private String ip;
private boolean window1;
private boolean window2;
[...]

}
```

While loading from this JSON how can i make `ObjectMaper()` to understand that the `"yyyy-MM-dd"` is the field name and value ?

Comment: JSON is simple, it only has a key-value pairs. Your data should be one of these.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` annotations on the fields having LocalDate as their type -

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
```

Comment: I can not see LocalDateDeserializer.class My dependencies are <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.6</version>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jsonSchema</artifactId>
    
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>

Comment: it should be in another jar - jackson-datatype-jsr310: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.6

Comment: So i added that and i still get this error 
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `jsonTemplate.SundayJsonTemplate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String) [rest of json...] from this line of code SundayJsonTemplate readValue = ob.readValue(jsonToSaved, SundayJsonTemplate.class);

Comment: can you also add a default constructor in SundayJsonTemplate?

Comment: i had this public SundayJsonTemplate(LocalDate date, ArrayList<SundayServerValue> sundayServerValueList) {
  this.date = date;
  this.setSundayServerValueList(sundayServerValueList);
 }

Comment: added this after wrote the comment public SundayJsonTemplate() {
 }Now i get this error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "2018-08-05" (class jsonTemplate.SundayJsonTemplate), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "sundayServerValueList", "date"])
 at

Comment: can you update the code based on the @JsonDeserialize?

Comment: you need to remove @JsonFormat annotation

Comment: I have deleted it and still get the same error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "2018-08-05" (class jsonTemplate.SundayJsonTemplate), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "sundayServerValueList", "date"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"2018-08-05":

Comment: thats primarily because of the format of the date you have. Default is not yyyy-MM-dd. You can use - https://gist.github.com/rishikeshdhokare/1f698184fb1c4076201b9854005bab81 with your version of DateTimeFormater

Comment: I will check, but it is weird because i got this format form ObjectMapper String jsonToSaved = ob.writeValueAsString(sundayUpdateDateMap);

Comment: I updated my code and still get the same com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "2018-08-05"

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this if someone just need a working solution.

First i need to admit that i gave up after spedning to much hours on this problem.
I wanted to make this as optimal as possible and learn but i dont want to waste more time right now.

This is what work for me to deserialize this JSON

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String, ArrayList<SundayServerValue>>> typeReference = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,ArrayList<SundayServerValue>>>(){};


        HashMap<String, ArrayList<SundayServerValue>>
        map = ob.readValue(loadStringFromFile, typeReference);
```

After this I just create a new map and convert in it `String` to `LocalDate`.